# Does Monk's Resolve passive work vs Bosses / with AoE?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I haven't been able to determine if the Monk's passive [Resolve](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/resolve) works as a debuff vs. every mob there is. I'm planning on using [Deadly Reach](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach) with the armor buff and Resolve to apply damage reduction all around for my party and to be more tanky. Does anyone know  whether bosses are immune to the damage reduction debuff, and whether it would be applies for AoE attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it DOES affect bosses, and it triggers off anything that deals % weapon damage (the damage dealing components of all monk abilities).